# jquery with variable php

Tags: php, jquery, attr

I have this code php

```
        ............................
      ..............................
        .................
        <input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" stock="        

         <?php if ($option_value['subtract']) { ?>
        <?php if ($option_value['quantity'] >= 3) { ?>
          <?php echo $text_in_stock; ?>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php if ($option_value['quantity'] < 3 && $option_value['quantity'] > 0) { ?>
           <?php echo $option_value['quantity']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $text_pcs_only; ?>
          <?php } ?>
       <?php if ($option_value['quantity'] <= 0) { ?>
           <?php echo $text_out_of_stock; ?>    
      <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>


        " value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" onchange="recalculateprice();" />


        <div class="pippo">
        .................
      .......
        </div>
```

then I have this script

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function recalculateprice()  {

 var stock = $('#style_stock').attr('stock');

$('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function() {
   $('.pippo').hide();
if ($(this).attr('stock') != '<?php echo $text_out_of_stock; ?>') {
    $('.pippo').show()
    stock = $(this).attr('stock');  
    }
});
```

I need hide div pippo when check an option with stock = . But the attr stock in option radio has some if ....
What I have insert in this row ?

```
     if ($(this).attr('stock') != '<?php echo $text_out_of_stock; ?>') {
```

Comment: You are merging PHP and HTML, please try to avoid this as it significantly reduces readability of your code.

Comment: `stock` is not a valid HTML attribute in all contexts. Use `data-stock` to pass a HTML5 validation test.

Answer (score 0):

i can't tell you exactly what is the problem 
but here are few important notes:-
first in PHP

- try to calculate the stock value outside the input tag stock attribute & echo the final value and remove the extra spaces.
- try to use "else if" instead of stacking "if" commands and making ambiguity in the value
  (its also easier)

second in Javascript

- the code you have written will always show the ".pippo" div in case if there at least on radio button with attribute `stock != out_of_stock`  so you need to make sure that you are testing the only changed radio.
- the value of the `$(this).attr('stock')` in the case you use the line directly  will be undefined as u didn't define it .
- finally the calling for `onChange` attribute will make some problems in page loading and may give you error of undefined function

so instead i prefer as long as you are using `jQuery` attach the events through `jQuery`

here is a full sample of may what you can use

HTML

```
   <div class="pippo">
        .................
      .......
        </div>
<input type="radio"  stock="...."  name="opt">
<input type="radio" checked="checked" stock="10" name="opt">
 <div id="style_stock" stock="10">stock = 10</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function recalculateprice(x)  {
         if ($(x).attr('stock') != '....') {            
            $('.pippo').show();
            //put the code you want
         }else{
             $('.pippo').hide();
            //put the code you want
         }
}
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    recalculateprice(this);                                        
});
```